# Mysql order by specific IDs first but still alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

Is there a way I can get specific IDs at the top, but sorted alphabetically by title, followed by the rest of the records also sorted alphabetically by title?

What I have right now:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(ID,2,3) DESC, title ASC`

Example:

```
1 Lisa
2 Hannah
3 Adam
4 Brian
```

Should be sorted

```
3 Adam (because Adam is before Hannah)
2 Hannah
4 Brian (because Brian is before Lisa)
1 Lisa
```

Comment: Hi - please can you provide a better explanation of your sorting rules? Why is Brian not before Hannah? Your question mentions specific ids but there’s no clear explanation of which ids you are referring to, how they effect the sort order, etc

Comment: is it sorteb by gender, wh then haven't you a column that has that information

Comment: @NickW I want to grab ID 2 and 3 (or whatever IDs I put in the query) and sort them alphabetically, then I want to grab the rest of the records and sort them alphabetically. So two groups basically. A selection of IDs first followed by the rest. Makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table
order by 
case when id in (2,3) 
then 0 
else 1 end asc, 
title asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need a use a CASE statement that generated different values for each group that you wanted and then order by the case statement and then by the name

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected. Any leads on what that may look like?

Comment: CASE WHEN id in this list of ids then 1 else 2 (pseudo code not actual code, obviously)

Answer (score 0):

From you smal sample data you can use a CASE WHEN and ORDER which fields should be at the start, the second order is name in my case

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tab1
>     (`id` int, `name` varchar(6))
> ;
>     
> INSERT INTO tab1
>     (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>     (1, 'Lisa'),
>     (2, 'Hannah'),
>     (3, 'Adam'),
>     (4, 'Brian')
> ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM tab1 ORDER BY 
> CASE WHEN FIELD(ID,2,3) THEN 1 ELSE 2  END  ASC,name ASC
> #, title ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name  
> -: | :-----
>  3 | Adam  
>  2 | Hannah
>  4 | Brian 
>  1 | Lisa
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=084d48576b2db72c061b203c70e5b516)*